# how do i add force in the direction the player is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So the code is on a object that makes the player bounce and it gets the  rb and adds a force that makes it go up but I would like it also to give the player a boost in the direction their facing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bounce : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(100, 10000)]
    public float bouncehight;

    [Range(100, 10000)]
    public float boost;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        GameObject bouncer = collision.gameObject;
        Rigidbody rb = bouncer.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * bouncehight);

        //so here i would call or something 

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * boost *look);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the direction vector of a `GameObject` via [`Transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html).

This would probably be something like `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * boost)`

Comment: yea i tried that but the problem is that it shoots me off in the same direction no matter which way i am facing. i would like the force to move me in the direction i am facing.

Comment: if you're shooting off in the same direction, no matter what, then you're moving the wrong object (or you're not rotating the right object) make sure that you're moving the same object that you're rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use transform.forward:

```
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forceAmount)
```

Alternatively you can count it yourself for the same result:

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * transform.rotation * forceAmount)
```

Edit: since you are inside bounce class transform.forward refers to the bounce, hence always the same direction. Use rb.gameObject:

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * rb.gameObject.transform.rotation * forceAmount)
```

Or

```
  rb.AddForce(rb.gameObject.transform.forward * forceAmount)
```

to refer to the player's rotation instead

Comment: yea i tried that but the problem is that it shoots me off in the same direction no matter which way i am facing. i would like the force to move me in the direction i am facing.